# Synchornised method on java

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm new to java and I'm reading the java concurrent topics.

Here I've found that the using the `synchronised` keyword (for methods) only one thread can access that method.

Does it applies only to the shared object or to all the objects of that type. i.e.

I have a class named `A`, it has a synchronised method `foo()`,

I create two objects `a1`, and `a2`.

There are four threads `t1, t2, t3 and t4`.

```
t1 and t2 share a1
```

and

`t3 and t4 share a2`.

t1 access method foo, at the same time will the t3 able access the same method on a2.

Comment: As this is part of studying I suggest to write a "learning test" to verify your assumptions.

Comment: "I've found that the using the synchronised keyword (for methods) only one thread can access that method."  That is not correct.  You lock objects, not methods.  Multiple threads can be in the same method, on different objects, however multiple threads cannot be active in different synchronized methods for the same lock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Understand it like a1 object has separate memory space with its data members and member functions. Similarly a2 is having different memory space. Now you shared a1 with t1 and t2. When t1 and t2 threads will run whoever will first get the lock on a1 will be executing the foo().
But t1 and t3 access different objects of class A i.e. a1 and a2. In this case it possible that both thread t1 and t3 run at the same time with foo() but on their respective objects on which they are holding the lock.

Comment: do you think of a singularity or about string theory. Should be a Joke your right just wanted to bring some fun into play

Answer (score 0):

It applies to each instance of that class. If the method were `static` and `synchronized` it would apply for all instances.

Answer (score 0):

```
synchronized void myMethod() {
  ...
}
```

is the same as

```
void myMethod() {
  synchronized(this) {
    ...
  }
}
```

I.e., it just locks the whole object, no other thread will be able to enter any method on this object while one is in this method.

Answer (score 0):

Using the synchronized keyword to a non static method only locks the object itself. So in your case t1 and t3 should be able to access the foo method of a1 and a2 respectively at the same time.

If you need to have the lock for all instances you need to use both static and synchronized.

see the "Locks In Synchronized Methods" section of this page for more details.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html

Answer (score 0):

Note that `synchronized` is a short hand for `synchronized(this)`, where the argument of synchronized is the lock.

The method can only be accessed by one thread who then owns the lock.

This answers your question. If you have two locks (two classes) then the method will run in parallel for the two owners of the two locks.